# Text field not working on converting swf file to html5 using swiffy

Tags: html, mobile, flash

I have following issues on conversion:

- 1. Text field not working on converting swf file to html5 using swiffy..
- 2. some animation are not working..
- 3. There is also sound problem in in some browser.

Is there any way to identify the textfield actions ?

I have googled but nothing works.. I think they are saying use js.

Answer (score 0):

1) The key is to send the value to the swiffy object with this line in **javascript**:

> function sendValue() {
>               myValue=inputFieldName.value;
>               stage.setFlashVars('myMessageFromTextfield='+myValue);
>           }

2) Then, inside the fla file, in **actionscript2**, get the value:

> getValue = function() {
>       if(_level0.myMessageFromTextfield == "undefined" || _level0.myMessageFromTextfield == undefined) {
>           this.cat.animCat.myText.text = "";
>       } else {
>           this.cat.animCat.myText.text = _level0.myMessageFromTextfield;
>           returnButton._visible = true;
>       }
>   }

3) You need to constantly monitor when te data apears so use a setInterval:

> myInterval = setInterval(this, "getValue", 100);

4) Now, to send the value back to html file, we use getURL with the data attached:

> returnButton.onRelease = function() {
>       getURL("Javascript:showMessage('"+_level0.myMessageFromTextfield+" says the cat');");
>   }

5) And finally, again in **javascript** inside the html we execute the function with the parameter:

> function showMessage(message) {
>               alert(message);
>           }

It works perfectly in IE, Firefox, Chrome, safari (ios).

So you now can send text in ipad or iphone.

I attached the source files in the next link:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E64343A7ADE7D670!1401&authkey=!AO86aUEdyZRqQN4&ithint=file%2czip

Hope this help you (I've been trying to solve this during many months and until today i could).